# Use AJAX and link it to html file (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hyperlink, frontend

I have written AJAX in .js file. I'm not sure how to link it to the html file. Below is the JS file I have written:

```js
function spin(){
  $("#sq-two").toggleClass("spinEffect");
}
```

Comment: Add at the bottom of the `HTML` file after all HTML code and before the `</body>` tag in a script with `src` attribute.

Comment: Not to be picky. But I think you meant you have written JavaScript in a .js file. The JavaScript in your example does not yet include any AJAX.

Comment: You can also link it above the body if you put it inside of a window.onload or $.ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `<head>` element, add a new tag:

```html
<script src="./path_to_your_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Once your JavaScript is connected (along with jQuery), you'll still need something to initiate the spin function!